Programmatically show the Windows Emoji Panel?
On Windows 10/11 the Windows Emoji Panel can be invoked by pressing the keys WIN+. (Windows key + period key)
I tried to simulate the pressing of these keys:
procedure ShowEmojiPanel;
var
  Inputs: array[0..3] of TInput;
begin
  // Simulate pressing the Windows Key
  ZeroMemory(@Inputs, SizeOf(Inputs));
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_LWIN;

  // Simulate pressing the '.' key
  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := Ord('.');

  // Simulate releasing the '.' key
  Inputs[2].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[2].ki.wVk := Ord('.');
  Inputs[2].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  // Simulate releasing the Windows Key
  Inputs[3].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[3].ki.wVk := VK_LWIN;
  Inputs[3].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  // Send the inputs
  SendInput(4, Inputs[0], SizeOf(TInput));
end;

procedure ShowEmojiPanel;
begin
  // Press WIN key
  keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0);

  // Press period (.)
  keybd_event(Ord('.'), 0, 0, 0);

  // Release period (.)
  keybd_event(Ord('.'), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

  // Release WIN key
  keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
end;

However, it seems that none of these procedures is able to open the Windows Emoji Panel on my Windows 11.
Is there another way to programmatically show the Windows Emoji Panel?

Your SendInput approach should work if you specify VK_OEM_PERIOD instead of Ord('.').

CharProbe is a very important and useful tool!
